# Will 8 speed shifters work on 6 speed cassette?

Tags: compatibility, shifting, road

I currently have a Shimano tourney 6-7 speed rear derailleur that is pulled by some 6 speed downtube index shifters, and a 6 speed Shimano cassette. The shifting is perfect. But I want to get some Shimano Sora STI shifters, they're 8 speed. Will the shifters work with my cassette?

Answer (score 5):

## Easy answer

No, this won't work with 8 speed indexed shifters. The reason is that one click on your shifter doesn't move your derailleur enough to shift to the next cog on your 6 speed cassette.

**Explanation**
[If we check a table of cable pulls](https://www.cyclinguk.org/cyclists-library/components/transmission-gears/derailleur-gears/shimergo), we see that a 6 speed Shimano cassette has a *pitch* of 5.5mm. Simply said, this means that the distance between 2 cogs on the cassette is 5.5mm.
An 8 speed cassette on the other hand as a *pitch* of 4.8mm. An 8 speed shifters will thus be indexed to move the derailleur 4.8mm on each click, 0.7mm less than you need.

## Complex answer

An 8 speed shifter won't move your derailleur enough to shift to the next cog, lacking 0.7mm on each click.
*Pitch* however is described by the *shift ratio* of your derailleur and the *cable pull* of your shifter. For Shimano 6, 7, 8 and 9 speed, the *shift ratio* is 1.7 (moving the shifting cable by 1mm moves your derailleur by 1.7mm).

What you might be looking for, if you want to do some hacking are tricks to manipulate the *shift ratio*. On the bottom of [this webpage](https://highpath.co.uk/cycle-information-rear-derailleurs-and-indexing/), a number of alternative routings are described. In your case, you could try if routing #2 or #3 would work. However, fine tuning the *cable pull* is not very simple, and might need some trail-and-error and drilling (in case the obtained cable pull is too large).